# How to create session on html link click in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

In my laravel project I have a view-client page with  link named "add contract" for that particular client.Here I have to send the client_id to "contract/create" link so how can I pass my client_id to contract page to default selected the client_id in contract page. Is there any way on link click to create session or any other way to over weigh it.

Add contract link in client view page.

```
<a href="javascrip:void(0)" name="addcontract"  class="btn bg-info-300">+Add Contract</a>
```

Comment: it seems you are using form. why don't you use hidden input tag for your purpose?

Comment: I just updated my code.